# How to make org-mode DWIM when it reads times in timestamps?

Tags: org-mode, parse-time

**Q:** how can I make `org-mode` read the time in timestamps intelligently?

`org-mode` uses `org-read-date` (which in turn relies on `parse-time-string`) to create/modify timestamps, scheduled items, and deadlines.  I'm trying to figure out how to make it smarter when it reads in the time of an event.

One can enter times:

- on a 24-hour clock (`9:00` => 9:00AM, `21:00` => 9:00PM), or
- with AM or PM suffixes (`9am` => 9:00AM, `9pm` => 9:00PM).

That's all well and good, but here's where I'd like it to be smarter in a DWIM fashion.  There are whole stretches of the day during which, on a 12-hour clock, I *always* mean PM (ie, for times in the middle of the night).  For example, if I enter `2:00`, I *always* mean "2:00PM", but on the 24-hour clock it means "2:00AM".  The problem is that I commonly forget to append the `pm` part, and then my agenda informs me that the meeting I have for 2:00 in the afternoon is actually scheduled for 2:00 in the morning.

So: how can I convince `org-read-date` to accept a range of times to mean PM unless I explicitly add the `am` suffix?  I'd like to be able to enter any time from, say, `1:00` to `6:59` and have it mean 1:00PM to 6:59PM unless I explicitly enter something like `1:00am`.

*NB:* see [this related thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2589/how-to-make-org-mode-understand-alternate-day-month-abbreviations) on getting `org-mode` to understand alternative day/month abbreviations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`org-read-date-analyze` is the underlying function for parsing
the input with `org-mode` time format, e.g., understanding AM/PM suffixes.
It is a complicated function containing many parts, and IMO `advice` is the
easiest way. Below is an example. This advice adds 12 hours to
the final time when the input doesn't contain `am` and the final
time is between `1:00` and `6:59`.

For the new `advice` system in Emacs 24.4:

```
(defvar time-range-with-pm-suffix '("1:00" . "6:59"))

(defun org-analyze-date-dwim (original-fun ans org-def org-defdecode)
  (let* ((time (funcall original-fun ans org-def org-defdecode))
         (minute (nth 1 time))
         (hour (nth 2 time))
         (minutes (+ minute (* 60 hour)))
         s)
    (when (and (< hour 12)
               (not (string-match "am" ans))
               (>= minutes (org-hh:mm-string-to-minutes (car time-range-with-pm-suffix)))
               (<= minutes (org-hh:mm-string-to-minutes (cdr time-range-with-pm-suffix))))
      (setf (nth 2 time) (+ hour 12))
      (when (boundp 'org-end-time-was-given)
        (setq s org-end-time-was-given)
        (if (and s (string-match "^\\([0-9]+\\)\\(:[0-9]+\\)$" s))
            (setq org-end-time-was-given
                  (concat (number-to-string (+ 12 (string-to-number (match-string 1 s))))
                          (match-string 2 s))))))
    time))

(advice-add 'org-read-date-analyze :around #'org-analyze-date-dwim)
```

For the old `defadvice`:

```
(defvar time-range-with-pm-suffix '("1:00" . "6:59"))

(defadvice org-read-date-analyze (around org-analyze-date-dwim activate)
  (let ((ans (ad-get-arg 0))
        minute hour minutes s)
    ad-do-it
    (setq minute (nth 1 ad-return-value)
          hour (nth 2 ad-return-value)
          minutes (+ minute (* 60 hour)))
    (when (and ans
               (< hour 12)
               (not (string-match "am" ans))
               (>= minutes (org-hh:mm-string-to-minutes (car time-range-with-pm-suffix)))
               (<= minutes (org-hh:mm-string-to-minutes (cdr time-range-with-pm-suffix))))
      (setf (nth 2 ad-return-value) (+ hour 12))
      (when (boundp 'org-end-time-was-given)
        (setq s org-end-time-was-given)
        (if (and s (string-match "^\\([0-9]+\\)\\(:[0-9]+\\)$" s))
            (setq org-end-time-was-given
                  (concat (number-to-string (+ 12 (string-to-number (match-string 1 s))))
                          (match-string 2 s))))))))
```