# How to make org-mode timestamps understand a new abbreviation for "tomorrow"?

Tags: org-mode, parse-time

**Q:** How can I make `org-read-date` understand an abbreviation that calls a function that returns tomorrow's day of the week?

The super-short version: I'm trying to get the timestamp functionality of `+1d` when typing `tom` as a more finger-friendly way of saying "tomorrow."

This question follows up on [this thread on dates](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2589/how-to-make-org-mode-understand-alternate-day-month-abbreviations) and [this thread on times](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/how-to-make-org-mode-dwim-when-it-reads-times-in-timestamps).

I'm trying to train `org-read-date` to understand new, easier-to-type abbreviations when I'm entering timestamps, scheduled items, and deadlines.  In particular, when entering a timestamp, I'd like to be able to enter `tom` and have `org-read-date` recognize it as "whatever day tomorrow is" (yes, I know I can type `+1d`, but it's an awfully awkward sequence of keys).

The `parse-time` functionality on which `org-read-date` relies expects an integer from 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday).  Fair enough, here's a little function that does it:

```
(defun tomorrow-day ()
  "Returns the day of the week for tomorrow."
  (let ((day (1+ (string-to-number (format-time-string "%w")))))
    (if (= day 7)
        0
      day)))
```

I'm stuck at the following point.  Following [this prior thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2589/how-to-make-org-mode-understand-alternate-day-month-abbreviations), I've `push`ed this function onto the `parse-time-weekdays` alist:

```
(push `("tom" . ,(tomorrow-day)) parse-time-weekdays)
```

Here's the problem: quasi-quoting pushes the *literal value* that `tomorrow-day` returns *only at the time it was first evaluated* (so, if today is Monday, `tom` refers to day number 2 from here to eternity).  Instead, I need `tomorrow-day` evaluated each time I invoke `tom` when entering a timestamp.  Why?  Because I commonly leave an Emacs session running for days at a time, meaning that `tom` no longer refers to "tomorrow" after the day on which it was evaluated.

I've tried various forms of quoting and quasi-quoting, and eventually got quite silly with an intricate combination of `funcall`s and `eval`s, all to no avail.

So: **how do I get this function (`tomorrow-day`) evaluated every time I enter `tom` in a timestamp?**

Comment: How about modifying `org-read-date-analyze` to transform your abreviation into whatever you want -- e.g., `(when (string-match . . .`?  You'll probably be most interested in transforming the value of `ans` -- when `ans` is `tom`, make it `+1d` instead.  You could also catch `ans` and modify it beforehand -- e.g., by modifying it inside `org-read-date` -- before `final` is set.

Comment: @lawlist, thanks for the suggestion.  `org-read-date-analyze` makes my head spin.  Although I found an alternate way to get what I was after, I'll dig into that function for other modifications.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like we can build on **@lawlist**'s idea and do something similar to this:

```
(advice-add 'org-read-date-analyze :around
            (lambda (orig ans org-def org-defdecode)
              (funcall orig (if (string-match "tom" ans) "+1d" ans) org-def org-defdecode)))
```

Comment: Some whitespace is getting mixed in with the `ans` -- `(if (string-match "tom" ans) "+1d" ans)` should fix it.  If you put in a message for `ans`, you'll see what I mean -- some stuff gets appended to the end that looks like whitespace.

Comment: @lawlist: The unfortunate thing is that now "atom", "tom-tom" and so on also mean "tomorrow".

Comment: Then we need a tighter regexp -- `"^tom +$"` or something like that.  Or, we need to figure out exactly what type of whatspace is being inserted so  a `string=` can work.

Comment: Looks like `org-read-date-display` appends a space to the string typed in by the user until it gets something ending in four spaces. I wish I knew why it does that. Other callers of `org-read-date-analyze` don't do that (as far as I can tell), so I would use `"^tom *$"`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a somewhat convoluted way to get the functionality without modifying `org-read-date` or `org-read-date-analyze`.  It uses the same approach in the question, but defining a timer that runs every 24-hours at midnight that resets the value of `tom`:

```
(defun tomorrow-day ()
  "Returns the day of the week for tomorrow."
  (let ((day (1+ (string-to-number (format-time-string "%w")))))
    (if (= day 7)
        0
      day)))

(eval-after-load 'parse-time
   '(progn
     (setq parse-time-weekdays (nconc parse-time-weekdays
                                      `(("tom" . ,(tomorrow-day))))
     (defvar parse-time-tomorrow-timer
       (run-at-time "12am"
                    (* 24 60 60)
                    (lambda ()
                      (setf (cdr (assoc "tom" parse-time-weekdays))
                            (tomorrow-day))))
       "Timer to reset the day to which \"tom\" refers in timestamps.")))
```

What it lacks in elegance, it makes up in obscurity!